# Adding bearer token to swagger requests using swagger-client

Tags: reactjs, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-3.0

I'm trying to add a bearer JWT token to a swagger request upon login of an account but I can't seem to get it working. The documentation leaves a lot to be desired.

`const SWAGGER_CLIENT = SwaggerClient(".../api.yml");`

`const carsResponse = await SWAGGER_CLIENT.client.execute({ operationId: "getCars" }); // I need { Authorizations: Bearer ${token}} here`

If it's not possible to add it there then I can always create the client above with the token upon a successful login.

I think the issue is the syntax more than anything. There is virtually no documentation on how to use the `.execute()` method which is very frustrating. FWIW; I'm using the execute method and passing in tag names to make it more reusable than using the generated functions e.g., `getCars(), addCar()` etc. I don't know if this is the "right" way to use Swagger but it makes sense to me.

Is  possible to add it globally so I needn't include it in every request? The token will need to be added upon a successful login. It's a CRA application using Redux.

Comment: Here are some docs for `.execute`: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/master/docs/usage/try-it-out-executor.md

Comment: Thank you Helen! This really helped. I couldn't find these, and I think the 'TryItOutExecutor' title sounds very misleading. I can see the authorization header now, although get a 403 CORS issue which is being investigated by the person responsible to fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We will be [renaming](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1742) **Try It Out Executor** to **HTTP client for OAS operations**. Thanks for your input!